# Update values in column in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table 
I want to update the status from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 in a single query

```
    ID        Name           Status
------------------------------------------
    1          Ben             0
    2          John            1
    3          Mark            0
    4          Gates           0
    5          Ricky           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column status can be `null` or status can have more than two values, this solution should work for you.

```
update tab
   set status = case 
                  when status=0 then 1
                  when status=1 then 0
                end
```

Answer (score 6):

Plenty of ways to do this, as the number of answers already show. Mine would just be:

```
UPDATE [Table] set status = 1-status
```

If there are non-0 and non-1 rows in the table that shouldn't be touched, I'd also add:

```
WHERE status in (0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two values (e.g 0 and 1) try this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Status = CASE WHEN Status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```